# Stop text from appearing at the bottom of text input box

Tags: html, css

I have a text input box, and for whatever reason any text entered in it is appearing at the bottom

```css
input {
 padding-top: 100px;
 width: 500px;
}

input[type=text] {
 border: 2px solid darkgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
```

```html
<input type='text'/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you set a huge padding-top so what did you expect? what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-top: 100px;` and replace that with `padding-bottom:100px;` from `css` code and problem is solve ,because `padding-top` is entered the text to bottom of text input box.

```css
input {
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 width: 500px;
}

input[type=text] {
 border: 2px solid darkgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
```

```html
<input type='text'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `padding-top: 100px;` from CSS code.  If you want to keep the height then set `height` or `padding-bottom`.

Answer (score 2):

replace `padding-top` with `padding-bottom` if you want to keep the height or remove the `padding-top`. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `padding-top` is causing this. Set it to a smaller value, like 10px.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input {
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 width: 500px;
}

input[type=text] {
 border: 2px solid darkgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
```

```html
<input type='text'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `padding-top` or give the same `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`,
you can also use `height` property

```
input {
    padding: 100px 0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

or

```
input {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

These code are center the text. if you want to the top use `padding-bottom` property

```
input {
   padding-bottom: 100px;
   width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use padding:15px; instead of padding-top , it is standard padding in bootstrap or any other framework, and if you want big input box then use textarea, , and increase the row value if you want to increase the height, or you can adjust the height through css as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's `padding-top` that creates this issue. If you wish to make the input field bigger use `height` along with `width` instead of `padding`. Of course, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to make the input field bigger and text to appear in the middle of the field you could do something like this:

```css
input {
 height: 100px;
 width: 500px;
        text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
 border: 2px solid darkgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'/>
```